# MYSQL - How do you set ID to a number between 1000000000 and 2000000000 with 3 set letters in front?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if my title is a little confusing, I tried to explain my situation in as less words as possible, but I'll explain it more below:

I currently have a database of users and each is given an auto incremented id starting at 1. However, I want to make it so the id is set to something like:

a. nyc1678293123

So the beginning should contain "nyc" and then a random number between 1 billion and 2 billion.

You might ask why I want this, so here is 1 sentence explaining why:

I tried to create a system where I am able to send invoices (email) including the customer's order and I want to send them something like an "account number", which references back to the ID of the user. I want the id to be unique for the nyc office and london office, and I don't want the customer to be able to change 1 number and access another person's invoice, so I want to use big numbers. I understand this might not be the smartest thing to do, or might not be safe at all, but I just want to get a simple understanding of how this works.

At the moment, the ID is set to 1 through 50,000. It is incremented by 1 for each customer. I want to change the ID inside the mysql if possible to something like I explained above.

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.
Thank you everyone for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: don't do this.you'll [be surprised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) just how quickly you'll end up with collisions. if you want non-predictable data, then simply pad+encrypt your numbers. the encrypted form won't be predictable, and also makes it highly unlikely that fiddling with it will create a "reversible" value.

Comment: Oh yea I totally forgot about this. Thank You very much Marc.

Comment: What have you tried? There are CONCAT functions in MySQL. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to trick the user in showing and use a "fake" field for that. This field shows both the prefix and the number.

The autoincrement is always a number, but when you add an extra field like "prefix" to contain de 'NYC' text, you should be fine. I would also keep the autoincrement field, beacause it ensures a unique id in the database without any hassle.

An alternative could be that you create your own key entirely and let your imagination do the work, but then you need to make sure that you always generate unique values in a transaction safe manner. Can be done, of course, but the autoincrement is much easier.

Now for setting the initial value of an autoincrement field, you can use something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000000;
```

By default the autoincrement ID can be 2,147,483,647 for an unsigned value. That should be sufficient for what you describe. :-)

Keep in mind:

- I don't think you can give a maximum value to an autoincrement field. The field will just increment until it runs out of numbers, depending on its datatype.
- From a database perspective, the ID-field will still be the unique identifier of your record. The prefix is irrelevant. The prefix is your business rule, and that is perfectly fine.
- The numbers are still "predictable" in a way that autoincrement values, increment by one each time.

However you can always restrict your user that he or she needs to know the correct prefix in order to retrieve data. But that is *business logic* that you need to provide. Using a GUID as an identifier also solves that problem, but is less readable. Or a random number instead of an autoincrement (providing that you ensure it's uniqueness.. a hassle, IMHO).

If you format the key on display to be of a specific width, and pad the number with zeros, you can choose a lower value for the initial autoincrement. Like this (in a randomly chosen language -> PHP):

```php
$id = 12345;
$prefix = 'nyc';

$key_to_show = printf("%s%010d", $prefix, $id);

// 'nyc0000012345'
```

Good luck, mate.

Melle

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually thought about this earlier but I had also thought about the problem that Marc pointed out and they go hand in hand. But again, thank you for taking your time to explain it step by step, gave me a little more clear understanding.

Comment: You're welcome. In the answer I provide there will be no collisions, since the ID is still unique. But about the guessing-a-number part, Marc offers a solution with the encryption. But you need to ensure the uniqueness (and possibly also the readabiity of the key itself! Users will need to read and type them).